# React-Router and redirect not working any ideas?

Tags: react-router

I have an app that redirects the user to the `/products` URL when they arrive at the base URL.

I am using the newer syntax for `react-router`:

```
const baseroute = () => {
    return {
        path: '/',
        Redirect:'/products',
        childRoutes: [
            {
                path: '*',
                Redirect: '/product'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is in my `routes`:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    { products() }
    { about() }
    { baseroute() }
</Router>
```

Everything works great, *except* that the redirect does not work.

If a user goes here:

```
www.mydomain.com/about <--- great!
www.mydomain.com  ---> SHOULD redirect to
-----> www.mydomain.com/products
```

Or because there is no proper child root:

```
www.mydomain.com/whatever
-------> www.mydomain.com/products
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not working because the `Redirect` property is not correct. `Redirect` is a component, and not a property (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#redirect).

A better idea is to use the `onEnter` hook, which you can check the docs here:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#enter-and-leave-hooks

Basically you will say "when enter in this route, do that":

```
{
    path: '/my-path',
    onEnter: (nextState, replace) => {
        replace('/replaced-path');
    }
}
```

Note that `replace` is a function provided by `react-router`, so, it will do a `replace` on your path. If you need to access another URL, or force some kind of "refresh/redirect", you may use something like `location.href = "http://something"` inside `onEnter`.

More info about `onEnter` hook:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#enterhook

Also, I don't think that the `childRoutes` you provided are needed, since using `onEnter` on the parent route will handle that for you.

Hope it helps!